# how to make my dockerized microservice available for public consumption

Tags: docker

Hello everyone i just want to know that what is the preferred procedure or practice to make dockerized micro-services available for public consumption say i have two micro-services that are running in docker containers and i want them to be consumed by an external javascript client code. Naturally the docker container's ip wont be reachable from the client side javascript code so how will the services be consumed.

i know its pretty dumb but i am just beginning to explore docker and this thing just crossed my mind.

Comment: place Load balancer on the top of your two container and LB should be accesible from public.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you missed is just `How to publish or expose port`, see [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose):

Yes, the external did not know the container's ip, but it know the host's ip which store you container, so you could just let the client application to visit host's ip, and then route to container.

One example next, you could see if not use `-p`, although container open the port 8000, client can't visit it with host's ip. But, if enable `-p 8000:8000`, then client could visit it using host's ip, here is `10.192.244.188`, and host port `8000`, the traffic will route to container's internal port `8000`, so the external successfully visit container's service.

```
$ docker run -d python:3 python -u -m http.server
$ curl http://10.192.244.188:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.192.244.188 port 8000: Connection refused
$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 python:3 python -u -m http.server
$ curl http://10.192.244.188:8000
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Directory listing for /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for /</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href=".dockerenv">.dockerenv</a></li>
<li><a href="bin/">bin/</a></li>
<li><a href="boot/">boot/</a></li>
<li><a href="dev/">dev/</a></li>
<li><a href="etc/">etc/</a></li>
<li><a href="home/">home/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib/">lib/</a></li>
<li><a href="lib64/">lib64/</a></li>
<li><a href="media/">media/</a></li>
<li><a href="mnt/">mnt/</a></li>
<li><a href="opt/">opt/</a></li>
<li><a href="proc/">proc/</a></li>
<li><a href="root/">root/</a></li>
<li><a href="run/">run/</a></li>
<li><a href="sbin/">sbin/</a></li>
<li><a href="srv/">srv/</a></li>
<li><a href="sys/">sys/</a></li>
<li><a href="tmp/">tmp/</a></li>
<li><a href="usr/">usr/</a></li>
<li><a href="var/">var/</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```